# Is "very much" correct in these sentences?

Tags: grammaticality

1. > - This is very much a lady.
   > - This is very much a car.
2. > This is very much a story of a story.
3. > - He is very much a grind
   > - He is very much of a grind.

   Is there any major difference in these usages? Should I use *too much* or *very much*?

Comment: You'd usually say "*She* is very much a lady" rather than "This".

Answer (score 2):

I would like to throw some light upon the correct usage of 'very much', 'very much of' and 'too much of'. Let us start with the following sentences. The usage of 'too much' is not correct to my knowledge.

Rita is very much a lady.
Rita is very much of a lady.
Rita is too much of a lady.

**Rita is very much a lady.**: Here we mean that it is quite true that Rita is a lady. The emphasis is on the truth part of the sentence rather than on Rita being a lady.

**Rita is very much of a lady.**: Here we mean that Rita has a lot of ladylike characteristics. She is almost a lady but not entirely.

**Rita is too much of a lady.**: Such sentences are usually used in context with a particular result. In itself, the sentence holds no meaning, but when we append a finishing phrase to it, it becomes self-explanatory, such as - "Rita is too much of a lady to wear sport shoes." The implication is that Rita is so much of a lady that she would not wear sport shoes.

I hope it is clear.

Comment: Even though I am not the one who asked, but thank you very much for a very helpful answer. However, then what about changing the order of words as in the following? Do they still mean the same thing as you explained and are they correct sentences? **Rita is a lady very much. Rita is of a lady very much. Rita is of a lady too much.**

Comment: Is "very much" here an adverb?

Answer (score 1):

*[to be very much something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus/british/much)* is used to mean that it is very true/accurate.

> This (or better She) is very much a lady - a lady with typical characters of a woman, she's truly a lady, there's no denial.

When you use *very much **of** [something]* it means that it's too much a part/major part of that thing. Check this -

> After that encounter with Tanya, I started thinking very much of her.

*Too much* is an intense degree and is *generally* negative.

> [too much](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/too-much) - An intolerable, impossible, or exhausting situation or experience

So **too much** is different than **very much** and in your sentences, **too much** won't fix.

Comment: Thank you so much. However, what is the difference between these?He is very much a grind

 He is very much of a grind.

Comment: One is correct, and the other isn't.  :)  Remove the "very much" from the sentence, and it will be clearer: "He is a grind.  He is of a grind."  The first one is correct.  The "very much" simply emphasizes the characteristic.