# What does it mean to say that someone is "too much of a grind"?

Tags: vocabulary

> Sure he's a nice guy, but don't you think he's too much of a grind?

Would you please explain what **too much of a grind** means?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/18770/3281.

Comment: @DamkerngT. That's not a duplicate. This question is asking what the phrase *means*; that one is asking whether to use "too much" or "very much".

Comment: @starsplusplus Agree. Perhaps I should have said related. However, the phrase "too much" was mentioned and asked there, "very much a grind" was asked there, and yet nobody seemed to answer 'What does "very much (of) a grind" mean?'; though, arguably, looking it up in a dictionary would answer such a question.

Answer (score 1):

*Too much of a grind* probably means he's too boring, because he's too studious. Though he is a nice guy, he's always into study and that's why he's boring.

Yes, it's here. Note that the use is informal.

> [grind (n)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/grind_2) - a person who spends too much time working or studying

Comment: You might also want to include the use of the word as applied to a task or activity. *The daily grind* refers to going to work at a thankless occupation, and "grinding for levels/points/drops" is a common theme in online games. It wasn't directly asked in the question, but it's relevant.

Comment: What does grinding for levels/points/drops" is a common theme in online games mean?

Comment: I think you've got it the wrong way around. It's not that "he" *grinds away at his tasks* - it's that the ***speaker*** finds being with that person *grinding, boringly oppressive*. If he *did* want to convey the sense you set out, it would probably be expressed as *"he's such a **grinder**"* (but that usage isn't particularly common).

Comment: @nima_persian: It refers to the common situation where a player can repeat an action in order to gain a small benefit. In a number of online games, it is possible to repeatedly pick fruit/vegetables, or kill weak monsters, in order to accumulate money or loot. (A real-life parallel example would be a fruit picker. The job involves climbing a tree, filling a basket with fruit, climbing down, walking to the storage area, emptying the basket, and going back out for another load.) Wikipedia has an [article on the phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grinding_%28video_gaming%29).

Comment: A down vote. What did I do? ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the US, someone is "too much of a grind" if they are difficult/irritating/annoying or it otherwise takes an effort enjoy yourself if they're around.

"grinder" is *very different* and can refer to something from a sandwich to more 'mature' topics.